# very large matrix calculation in R efficiently

Tags: r, matrix, cosine-similarity, bigdata

I am very new in R. I have a data-set with  139 columns and more than 46.5k rows. I have measured pairwise cosine similarity matrices between rows in the data-set where one row will be compared with rest of the other rows and will be excluded during next iteration and the process will go on for rest of the data-set. This implementation work fine with small sample data-set e.g. with 500 rows. However, when i try to do this with whole data-set(46k) it gets nasty (i have waited almost 30 hours running the code but no output). Here is my implementation so-far:

```
library(reshape2)
library(lsa)


psm_sample <- read.csv("psm_final_sample.csv")
numRows = nrow(psm_sample)


##################################

normalize <- function(x) {
  return ( (2 * ((x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x))) ) - 1 )
}

##################################
cat_normalize <- function(x) {

  norm <-  ( (2 * ((x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x))) ) - 1 )
  return (ifelse(norm < 0 , -1, 1))
}

#############################

cat_gender <- function (sex){
  sex <- as.character(sex)

  if( sex == 'M' ) {
    return (as.integer(1))
  }
  else{
    return(as.integer(2))
  }
}

##################################

cat_admsn_type <- function (type){
  type <- as.character(type)

  if( type == 'EMERGENCY' ) {
    return(as.integer(1))
  }
  else if ( type == 'URGENT'){ 
    return(as.integer(2))
  }
  else{
    return(as.integer(3))
  }
}

#############################

cat_first_icu <- function (ficu){
  type <- as.character(ficu)

  if( ficu == 'CCU' ) {
    return(as.integer(1))
  }
  else if ( ficu == 'CSRU'){ 
    return(as.integer(2))
  }
  else if ( ficu == 'MICU'){ 
    return(as.integer(3))
  }
  else if ( ficu == 'NICU'){ 
    return(as.integer(4))
  }
  else if ( ficu == 'SICU'){ 
    return(as.integer(5))
  }
  else{
    return(as.integer(6))
  }
}

##################################

cat_last_icu <- function (licu){
  type <- as.character(licu)

  if( licu == 'CCU' ) {
    return(as.integer(1))
  }
  else if ( licu == 'CSRU'){ 
    return(as.integer(2))
  }
  else if ( licu == 'MICU'){ 
    return(as.integer(3))
  }
  else if ( licu == 'NICU'){ 
    return(as.integer(4))
  }
  else if ( licu == 'SICU'){ 
    return(as.integer(5))
  }
  else{
    return(as.integer(6))
  }
}

#################################################################################

gender <- sapply(psm_sample$gender,cat_gender)
admission_type <- sapply(psm_sample$admission_type,cat_admsn_type)
first_icu_service_type <- sapply(psm_sample$first_icu_service_type,cat_first_icu)
last_icu_service_type <- sapply(psm_sample$last_icu_service_type,cat_last_icu)

################################################################################

psm_sample_cont_norm_df <- as.data.frame(lapply(psm_sample[8:138], normalize))
psm_sample_cat_df <- data.frame(gender,admission_type,first_icu_service_type,last_icu_service_type)
psm_sample_cat_norm_df <- as.data.frame(lapply(psm_sample_cat_df, cat_normalize))

psm_temp_df <- cbind.data.frame(psm_sample[1], psm_sample_cat_norm_df, psm_sample_cont_norm_df)


row.names(psm_temp_df ) <- make.names(paste0("patid.", as.character(1:nrow(psm_temp_df ))))
psm_final_df <- psm_temp_df[2:136]

###############################################################################


#mycosine <- function(x,y){
#c <- sum(x*y) / (sqrt(sum(x*x)) * sqrt(sum(y*y)))
  #return(c)
#}

#cosinesim <- function(x) {
  # initialize similarity matrix
  #m <- matrix(NA, nrow=ncol(x),ncol=ncol(x),dimnames=list(colnames(x),colnames(x)))
  #cos <- as.data.frame(m)

  #for(i in 1:ncol(x)) {
    #for(j in i:ncol(x)) {
      #co_rate_1 <- x[which(x[,i] & x[,j]),i]
      #co_rate_2 <- x[which(x[,i] & x[,j]),j]  
      #cos[i,j]= mycosine(co_rate_1,co_rate_2)
      #cos[j,i]=cos[i,j]        
    #}
  #}
  #return(cos)
#}

cs <- lsa::cosine(t(psm_final_df))

cs_round <-round(cs,digits = 2)



#cs_norm <- as.data.frame(lapply(cs,normalize))
#print(cs_norm)
#print(cs_round)

##########################################

numCols = 3;
totalROws = (numRows * (numRows-1)) / 2;
result <- matrix(nrow = totalROws, ncol = numCols)
#result<- big.matrix( nrow = totalROws, ncol = numCols, type = "double",shared = TRUE)
#options(bigmemory.allow.dimnames=TRUE)

colnames(result) <- c("PatA","PatB","Similarity")

index = 1;
for (i in 1:nrow(cs_round)) {
  patA = rownames(cs_round)[i]
  for (j in i:ncol(cs_round)) {
    if (j > i) {
      patB = colnames(cs_round)[j]
      result[index, 1] = patA
      result[index, 2] = patB
      result[index, 3] = cs_round[i,j]

      index = index + 1;
    }
  }
}

print(result)

write.csv(result, file = "C:/cosine/output.csv", row.names = F)
#ord_result<-result[order(result[,3],decreasing=TRUE),]
#print(ord_result)
```

Under this circumstances, I can split the data-set into highest 10 sub-sets. Then, there will be 4650 rows in each data-sets. Hence, for 4650 rows it is still a very big matrix calculation and I have to wait for a very long time for the output.

I have tried with big-memory, ff and matrix packages with this implementation but no fruitful outcome with my knowledge.

Any kind of suggestion or code modification or how to do it efficiently will be very much helpful for me.

Note:My machine has 8GBDDR3 RAM and i3 Processor with 2.10GHz clock speed.I am using 64 bit R studio.

Link for whole data-set(46.5 KRows - psm_final_without_null.csv) >> https://1drv.ms/u/s!AhoddsPPvdj3hVVFC-yl1tDKEfo8

Link for sample data-set(4700 Rows - psm_final_sample.csv) >> https://1drv.ms/u/s!AhoddsPPvdj3hVjrNTgkV0noqMk8

Comment: Where is `psm_final_sample.csv`?

Comment: @F.Privé Please check the edited links kindly. 
Link for sample data-set(4700 Rows - psm_final_sample.csv) >> https://1drv.ms/u/s!AhoddsPPvdj3hVjrNTgkV0noqMk8

Comment: What is the purpose of `which(x[,i] & x[,j])`. These are not logical?

Comment: @F.Privé Yes i can remove this cosinesim and the loop with lsa::cosine from lsa library but implementation has the same results !! :( 
Stucked on it !!

Comment: Do you _really_ want a 46500 x 46500 distance matrix?

Comment: @HongOoi >> Literally "NO". As i have said in the question, in this case, it is possible to split the data set into 10 equal sized sub-sets with 4650 rows each. I really want 4650X4650 matrix for now !!

Comment: @MdShakawathHossain Really, this is not very difficult. I just don't understand what's the purpose of `which(x[,i] & x[,j])`? Without it, this is just a `tcrossprod` with a scaling afterwards.

Comment: @F.Prive as I have said before the calculation is pairwise where one row will be compared with rest of the other rows and then it will be excluded  and the iterations will go on for rest of the data. Did you manage to execute the output with sample data (4650) rows ? Let me know please 

Comment: @F.Privé  I have removed the function and loop with lsa::cosine. Please check the edited code now.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite some space to optimize the code/algorithm. Just to name a few:

```
co_rate_1 <- x[which(x[,i] & x[,j]),i]
co_rate_2 <- x[which(x[,i] & x[,j]),j]
```

the main computation burden is the `which` function, apparently you don't have to compute twice, btw `which` is usually a slow function and it's generally not a good idea to use it in a computationally intensive code. **Update:** I don't think `which` is necessary here, you can safely remove it.

The resulting matrix from `cosinesim` is a symmetric matrix, which means you actually only need to compute half the elements.

The for loop you are using in the function constitutes a "embarrassingly parallel" problem, which means you can benefit from some simple implementation of parallel function such as `mclapply`.

Also I am sure rewriting `cosinesim` in Rcpp is gonna help a lot.

Comment: > It is possible to remove the cosinesim function and the loop  with lsa::cosine package. I have check with both cosinesim and lsa::cosine implementation but same results !!

As far as i know mclapply is not applicable for windows since i have windows 10 machine !! I have no idea about Rcpp since i am newbie in R.

Comment: windows uses `parLapply`, slightly more effort than `mclapply`.